# Re-use Query Parts in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very complicated stored procedure that repeats a very complicated query with different where clauses based on certain values passed in.  The stored procedure takes up over 500 lines of code, with the common part of the query taking up just over 100 lines.  That common part is repeated 3 times.

I originally thought to use CTE (Common Table Expressions) except in T-SQL you can't define the common part, do your `IF` statement and then apply the `WHERE` clause.  That's essentially what I need.

As a workaround I created a view for the common code, but it's only used in one stored procedure.

Is there any way to do this without creating a full view or temp tables?

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
WITH SummaryCTE (col1, col2, col3...)
AS
(
    SELECT concat("Pending Attachments - ", ifnull(countCol1, 0)) col1
    -- all the rest of the stuff
    FROM x as y
    LEFT JOIN attachments z on z.attachmentId = x.attachmentId
    -- and more complicated stuff
)

IF (@originatorId = @userId)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM SummaryCTE
    WHERE
       -- handle this security case
END
ELSE IF (@anotherCondition = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM SummaryCTE
    WHERE
       -- a different where clause
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM SummaryCTE
    WHERE
       -- the generic case
END
```

Hopefully the pseudo code gives you an idea of what I would like.  Right now my workaround is to create a view for the contents of what I defined `SummaryCTE` as, and then handle the `IF`/`ELSE IF`/`ELSE` clause.  Executing this structure will throw an error at the first `IF` statement because the next command is supposed to be a `SELECT` instead.  At least in T-SQL.

Maybe this doesn't exist in any other way, but I wanted to know for sure.

Comment: So the usual approach of including all WHERE predicates & negating them in their absence (`where @param is null or field = @param`) is not possible?

Comment: What is the argument against temporary tables?

Comment: If the select list is going to be the same and where clause different i would recommend that you use dynamic SQL with Parameters.

Comment: @AlexK. The where clause choices are pretty simple, but in the last case we declare a bunch more variables and check if the main record ID is in a massive list created by several UNIONed queries.  I think your approach would work if we didn't have the last clause do all that extra stuff.

Comment: @DanBracuk, It mostly has to do with data cleanup and the frequency in which we will be calling the function.  I haven't messed with temp tables in  years, but my experience back then has made me shy away from relying on them for future work.

Comment: A view is probably the best way to handle this, if code-minimization is that important to you.  A view is global to the database, a CTE is basically a query-local view.  Unfortunately there's nothing in-between, like a procedure-local view or function.  As @becuzz points out, dynamic-SQL works, but there are a lot of additional considerations and baggage with dynamic-sql so its use should be reserved for only those cases where it is needed for functional and/or performance reasons.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, more important than code-minimization is code-duplication.  I have been bitten more times than I care to tell because I remembered to change the code in one or two clauses but missed it in the last one.  The changes were too easy to overlook.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch That's called edit-sensitivity (or DRY these days) and it is definitely not normally considered to be more important than the security or even maintenance issues raised by Dynamic SQL.  Dynamic Sql does have it's place (I use it extensively), but that place is addressing functional and performance requirements that cannot be addressed any better way.  And even then it should be thoroughly vetted by someone who understands the security issues.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Understood.  I'm not too worried about dynamic SQL, as long as I know it's doing the right thing.  A lot of the complications in the stored proc is because the original developers were having the database do what application code does better.  It's out of scope to address right now.  I will have our DBA validate the parameter sniffing cache problems.

Comment: Umm, my point is that you *should* be worried about using dynamic SQL for this, because it's not the right tool.  There are many things that application code can do better than SQL and code reuse is definitely one of them.  Trying to use dynamic SQL to solve that would be like a dentist trying to use a ball-peen hammer because they don't have a drill available.  In theory they could both be used to get rid of cavities in teeth, but in practice it should never be done because the hammer is the wrong tool for the job.  I would recommend using a View instead.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, which is the solution I have right now.  The longer term fix will be in a future sprint.

Comment: Back to temp tables.  Since this is a stored procedure, no cleanup is required.

Comment: I am curious, why the downvote on my question?  How can it be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, aside from the temp tables and views that you've identified, you could go with dynamic SQL to build the code then execute it.  This keeps you from having to repeat code, but makes it a bit hard to just deal with.  Like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'with myCTE (col1, col2) as ( select * from myTable) select * from myCTE'

if (@myVar = 1)
begin
    @sql = @sql + ' where col1 = 2'
end
else if (@myVar = 2)
begin
    @sql = @sql + ' where col2 = 4'
end
-- ...

exec @sql
```

Another option would be to incorporate your different where clauses into the original query.

```
WITH SummaryCTE (col1, col2, col3...)
AS
(
    SELECT concat("Pending Attachments - ", ifnull(countCol1, 0)) col1
    -- all the rest of the stuff
    FROM x as y
    LEFT JOIN attachments z on z.attachmentId = x.attachmentId
    -- and more complicated stuff
)
select *
from SummaryCTE 
where 
(
    -- this was your first if
    @originatorId = @userId
    and ( whatever you do for your security case )
)
or
(
    -- this was your second branch
    @anotherCondition = 1
    and ( handle another case here )
)
or
-- etc. etc.
```

This eliminates the if/else chain but makes the query more complicated.  It also can cause some bad cached query plans because of parameter sniffing, but that may not matter much depending on your data.  Test that before making a decision.  (You can also add optimizer hints to not cache the query plan.  You won't get a bad one, but you also take a hit on every execution to create the query plan again.  Test to find out, don't guess.  Also, a solution with a view and the if/else chain will suffer from the same parameter sniffing/cached query plan problem.)

Comment: Between the two options, the latter looks a bit more comprehensible at least.  We had to update the query because we changed rules on how some of the fields were used and this stored procedure was by far the largest problem area.  Having to remember to make the same change in 3 different near identical queries is a recipe for accidentally leaving something out.  Looks like there isn't a magic SQL construct that is perfectly fit for what I need though.  It wasn't posted here, but my last clause defines a number of new variables and assigns them from queries before doing more complicated things.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch As far as your last clause, if you can possibly set that stuff up beforehand you could try the last approach.  If things are really that complicated, you might want to try moving the if/else logic to your application / another stored proc that calls a stored proc for each situation (and then you could use a view to hold the common parts of the query).  That would (mostly) avoid the parameter sniffing problem and give each proc a well defined purpose.

Comment: Definitely for a future sprint.  I would restructure the data we get so that the application logic can handle the string concatenation and check calculations.  It's better suited for that anyway considering the small number of records we get back from the stored proc.